# XNA: Determine content name from source file path

Tags: c#, xna, pipeline

I am currently implementing the `Level` content type, which is supposed to represent a game level contents (most important, refer to textures stored separately). Input level data contains full path to source texture resources.

Problem: How to determine the resulting content "names" that I can write out into the compiled level content? The textures are supposed to be reused, so baking them into the level content would be a bad idea (waste of space). It is impossible to provide the names during content creation (e.g. within the level editor).

To give an example: Source file `Levels/Level01.level` refers to `Textures/Granite.png` and `Textures/Dirt.png` using their full path names. I would like to infer `Textures/Granite` and `Textures/Dirt` from that data at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution was to use the (not that well documented) `ExternalReference<T>` class instead of plain string names.

On the writer's side, the level content object contains `ExternalReference<TextureContent>` (or even `List<ExternalReference<TextureContent>>`) instance. When serialized (via `ContentWriter`), this takes care of adjusting the reference properly.

The reader's side is simplified to a plain `ContentReader.ReadObject<>` call, e.g.

```
public sealed class LocationReader : ContentTypeReader<Location>
{
    protected override Location Read(ContentReader input, Location existingInstance)
    {
        List<Texture2D> textures = input.ReadObject<List<Texture2D>>();
    }
}
```

NOTE: Take care to properly override the `GetRuntimeType()` method in your writer classes; this was the source of oddball `ReflectionReader<T>` issues for me.